# Box API adding geo-location to folders and files

Tags: geolocation, box-api

I'm creating an enterprise web app using the API. I thought I saw somewhere that Box.com files can be tagged with location data to let them show up on a map, but I can't find anything in the API?

Comment: Can you link to where you saw this capability mentioned?

Comment: @seanrose Nope I can't find it. I suspect it was a passing comment referring to the directory location of Box folders and files, not geo-coordinate "locations". Any suggestions still welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific convention for adding geo-data to Box files at this point in time. You can store the information as a comment on the file or as part of the file's description, but that information isn't guaranteed to be persistent, as the user can modify it. It's probably best to store this information in a separate database.